# join two tables which are not connected with a key

Tags: mysql

I need to make query like

```
SELECT * from exp_channel_fields join exp_channel_titles ON  entry_id = 31558 and channel_id = 5
```

so that query should pickup channel fields and values, where values stores in another table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_channel_fields` (
  `field_id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `site_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `group_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `field_label` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `field_instructions` text,
  `field_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
  `field_list_items` text NOT NULL,
  `field_pre_populate` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `field_pre_channel_id` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_pre_field_id` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_ta_rows` tinyint(2) DEFAULT '8',
  `field_maxl` smallint(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_required` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `field_text_direction` char(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ltr',
  `field_search` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `field_is_hidden` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `field_fmt` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'xhtml',
  `field_show_fmt` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
  `field_order` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_content_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'any',
  `field_settings` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`field_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `field_type` (`field_type`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=117 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_channel_data` (
  `entry_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `channel_id` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field_id_1` text,
  `field_ft_1` tinytext,
  `field_id_3` text,
  `field_ft_3` tinytext,
  `field_id_4` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `field_ft_4` tinytext,
  `field_id_5` text,
  `field_ft_5` tinytext,
  `field_id_6` text,
  `field_ft_6` tinytext,
  `field_id_7` text,
  `field_ft_7` tinytext,
  `field_id_8` text,
  `field_ft_8` tinytext,
  `field_id_10` text,
  `field_ft_10` tinytext,
  `field_id_11` text,
  `field_ft_11` tinytext,
  `field_id_12` text,
  `field_ft_12` tinytext,
  `field_id_15` text,
  `field_ft_15` tinytext,
  `field_id_16` text,
  `field_ft_16` tinytext,
  `field_id_18` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_18` tinytext,
  `field_id_19` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_19` tinytext,
  `field_id_20` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_20` tinytext,
  `field_id_21` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_21` tinytext,
  `field_id_22` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_ft_22` tinytext,
  `field_dt_22` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_id_23` text,
  `field_ft_23` tinytext,
  `field_id_24` text,
  `field_ft_24` tinytext,
  `field_id_25` text,
  `field_ft_25` tinytext,
  `field_id_26` text,
  `field_ft_26` tinytext,
  `field_id_27` text,
  `field_ft_27` tinytext,
  `field_id_28` text,
  `field_ft_28` tinytext,
  `field_id_29` text,
  `field_ft_29` tinytext,
  `field_id_30` text,
  `field_ft_30` tinytext,
  `field_id_31` text,
  `field_ft_31` tinytext,
  `field_id_32` text,
  `field_ft_32` tinytext,
  `field_id_33` text,
  `field_ft_33` tinytext,
  `field_id_34` text,
  `field_ft_34` tinytext,
  `field_id_35` text,
  `field_ft_35` tinytext,
  `field_id_36` text,
  `field_ft_36` tinytext,
  `field_id_37` text,
  `field_ft_37` tinytext,
  `field_id_38` text,
  `field_ft_38` tinytext,
  `field_id_39` text,
  `field_ft_39` tinytext,
  `field_id_40` text,
  `field_ft_40` tinytext,
  `field_id_41` text,
  `field_ft_41` tinytext,
  `field_id_42` text,
  `field_ft_42` tinytext,
  `field_id_43` text,
  `field_ft_43` tinytext,
  `field_id_44` text,
  `field_ft_44` tinytext,
  `field_id_46` text,
  `field_ft_46` tinytext,
  `field_id_47` text,
  `field_ft_47` tinytext,
  `field_id_48` text,
  `field_ft_48` tinytext,
  `field_id_49` text,
  `field_ft_49` tinytext,
  `field_id_50` text,
  `field_ft_50` tinytext,
  `field_id_51` text,
  `field_ft_51` tinytext,
  `field_id_52` text,
  `field_ft_52` tinytext,
  `field_id_53` text,
  `field_ft_53` tinytext,
  `field_id_54` text,
  `field_ft_54` tinytext,
  `field_id_55` text,
  `field_ft_55` tinytext,
  `field_id_56` text,
  `field_ft_56` tinytext,
  `field_id_57` text,
  `field_ft_57` tinytext,
  `field_id_58` text,
  `field_ft_58` tinytext,
  `field_id_62` text,
  `field_ft_62` tinytext,
  `field_id_63` text,
  `field_ft_63` tinytext,
  `field_id_64` text,
  `field_ft_64` tinytext,
  `field_id_65` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `field_ft_65` tinytext,
  `field_id_66` text,
  `field_ft_66` tinytext,
  `field_id_67` text,
  `field_ft_67` tinytext,
  `field_id_68` text,
  `field_ft_68` tinytext,
  `field_id_70` text,
  `field_ft_70` tinytext,
  `field_id_71` text,
  `field_ft_71` tinytext,
  `field_id_72` text,
  `field_ft_72` tinytext,
  `field_id_73` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_73` tinytext,
  `field_id_74` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_74` tinytext,
  `field_id_75` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_75` tinytext,
  `field_id_77` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_77` tinytext,
  `field_id_78` text,
  `field_ft_78` tinytext,
  `field_id_80` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_80` tinytext,
  `field_id_81` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_81` tinytext,
  `field_id_82` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_82` tinytext,
  `field_id_83` text NOT NULL,
  `field_ft_83` tinytext,
  `field_id_84` text,
  `field_ft_84` tinytext,
  `field_id_85` text,
  `field_ft_85` tinytext,
  `field_id_86` text,
  `field_ft_86` tinytext,
  `field_id_87` text,
  `field_ft_87` tinytext,
  `field_id_88` text,
  `field_ft_88` tinytext,
  `field_id_90` text,
  `field_ft_90` tinytext,
  `field_id_91` text,
  `field_ft_91` tinytext,
  `field_id_92` text,
  `field_ft_92` tinytext,
  `field_id_93` text,
  `field_ft_93` tinytext,
  `field_id_94` text,
  `field_ft_94` tinytext,
  `field_id_95` text,
  `field_ft_95` tinytext,
  `field_id_97` text,
  `field_ft_97` tinytext,
  `field_id_99` text,
  `field_ft_99` tinytext,
  `field_id_100` text,
  `field_ft_100` tinytext,
  `field_id_101` text,
  `field_ft_101` tinytext,
  `field_id_102` text,
  `field_ft_102` tinytext,
  `field_id_103` text,
  `field_ft_103` tinytext,
  `field_id_104` text,
  `field_ft_104` tinytext,
  `field_id_105` text,
  `field_ft_105` tinytext,
  `field_id_106` text,
  `field_ft_106` tinytext,
  `field_id_107` text,
  `field_ft_107` tinytext,
  `field_id_108` text,
  `field_ft_108` tinytext,
  `field_id_109` text,
  `field_ft_109` tinytext,
  `field_id_110` text,
  `field_ft_110` tinytext,
  `field_id_111` text,
  `field_ft_111` tinytext,
  `field_id_112` text,
  `field_ft_112` tinytext,
  `field_id_113` text,
  `field_ft_113` tinytext,
  `field_id_114` text,
  `field_ft_114` tinytext,
  `field_id_115` text,
  `field_ft_115` tinytext,
  `field_id_116` text,
  `field_ft_116` tinytext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`entry_id`),
  KEY `channel_id` (`channel_id`),
  KEY `site_id` (`site_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: You can `JOIN` the two tables even if there is no foreign key from one table into the other, you can join using any other columns. So, How they are related to each other then? I see there is `site_id` in both the two tables.

Comment: normalization nightmare

Comment: @Randy this expression engine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to join on matching fields, just use

```
SELECT * from exp_channel_fields join exp_channel_titles ON  entry_id = channel_id;
```

if the fields don't match, (have different values) you can join like this:

```
SELECT * from exp_channel_fields, exp_channel_titles WHERE entry_id = 31558 and channel_id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside being slow there is nothing that prevents joining both tables. You only need to find a column in both tables which can be used as a common join criteria.